# Runtime error in Java while testing problem solving. Am i doing the input part wrong on String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, runtime-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOk4y.png)Very simple problem but showing Runtime error on the site(beginner btw). Not so sure about the error, but i think the input part is incorrect(getting multiple strings from input). Is there any other ways to get input on String array? if there is, please let me know.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at ExcellentResult.main(ExcellentResult.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at _$SandboxExecutor.main(_$SandboxExecutor.java:38)`package examples0;
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int salary = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] tabs = new String[n];
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) tabs[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            switch (tabs[i]) {
                case "Facebook":
                    salary-=150;
                    break;
                case "Instagram":
                    salary-=100;
                    break;
                case "Reddit":
                    salary-=50;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(salary>0){
            System.out.println(salary);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You have lost your salary.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should share your input, as well as pointing out which line is line 14.

Comment: Also be aware that [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: 10
750
Facebook
Dev.bg
Instagram
Facebook
Reddit
Facebook
Facebook -- this is the input from the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be correct, this was the output that I got after running it:

```
    3
    1000
    Facebook
    Instagram
    750
```

Another way to get String inputs is by providing command line arguments when you run it and then access those strings through the "args". Your code will look like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int salary = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    
    for(int i=1; i<args.length; i++){
        switch (args[i]) {
            case "Facebook":
                salary-=150;
                break;
            case "Instagram":
                salary-=100;
                break;
            case "Reddit":
                salary-=50;
                break;
        }
    }
    if(salary>0){
        System.out.println(salary);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You have lost your salary.");
    }
}
```

You will have to run it using your terminal like:

```
    % javac <Name of class>.java
    % java <Name of class> 3000 Facebook Instagram Reddit
    2700
    % java <Name of class> 100 Facebook Instagram Reddit 
    You have lost your salary.
```

I hope this helps.